# SQlite unable to open

Tags: android

[image]
I create my database using sqliteadmin (version 0.8.3.2),I place this file into my asset directory and then copy this file into `data/data/mypackage/databases/mydb`,its ok.now when I am trying to open this file getting exception as `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file`,below code i am using to open the mydb.

```
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/src.com/databases/";
private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

try{ 
dbBF = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}catch(Exception ex)

{System.out.print("H![enter image description here][1]ere is an Exception"+ex);
}    
Cursor cur = dbBF.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM"+"myTable" , null);
```

Comment: Show us the code how do you open the database?

Comment: I edit my above post to add the method to open the SQLite ...

Comment: The file needs a .db extension?

Comment: no file no need .db extension

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems right. Do you have extension on the your database file? Like `mydb.db`. If you do than you should add it complete name of the file.

Comment: thansk,my SQLite file have no any extension,when i copy from asset directory to data directory that time also i did not put any extension ..

Comment: Is it copied in that directory? Check it in your `File Explorer` in your `DDMS perspective`

Comment: I plugout my device ,I run my emulator in DDMS view,I run my code and I see my database file exist in data/data/package/databases/mydb directory...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First please note that your database file should not be bigger than 1.2MB, and if it's, then try to split it. Second, instead of the following lines,

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.openDataBase(); //Bad! db not created yet!
```

try to use

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.createDataBase(); //needs exception handling
db.openDataBase();
```

I copied it from [How does android access a sqlite database included in the assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318784/how-does-android-access-a-sqlite-database-included-in-the-assets-folder) . Anyway, it works for me. In case of any problem, let me know.