# Where should I put a sqlite file in source android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm a new android developer.
I have an existing SQLite database.
My question is: where should I put it in my source?
And also: I want copy it to device upon installation.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 My question is: where should I put it in my source?
```

You can put the database into your assets folder of your application and then copy it into sdcard and use it.

Try out below code to copy database from assets folder to sdcard.

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mycontext;

    //private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    /*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                        + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/";*/

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
        this.mycontext=context;
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            //System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase(); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
        }
    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if(dbexist) {
            //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }   

    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(packagename)/databases   /(datbasename).sqlite");

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

}
```

And

```
 I want copy it to device upon installation.
```

Create the instance of the `DataBaseHelper`  class in your launcher activity as below and it will directly copy the database.

```
DataBaseHelper dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(MyActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your database in assets folder and this database is copy into sdcard and retrieve that databse from sdcard:

copy Database:

```
public static void copyDataBase(Context mActivity) throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(new File("/data/data/"
                + mActivity.getPackageName() + "/databases/" + "aman36.sqlite"));
        File files = new File("/sdcard/files/");
        files.mkdirs();
        String outFileName = "/sdcard/files/aman36.sqlite";
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength;
        while ((bufferLength = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
```

and you can access your path to retrieve databse ->sdcard->files->aman36.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Put your database.sqlite file in asset folder of project directory and retreive it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318784/how-does-android-access-a-sqlite-database-included-in-the-assets-folder) 
link.